# Using Docker API fails to create image

Tags: docker

I am trying to create container using Docker API. I am running:

```
 sudo curl \
     -XPOST --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock \
     -d '{"Image":"nginx"}' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     http://localhost/containers/create
```

but I get this message instead:

```
{"message":"No such image: nginx:latest"}
```

Shouldn't the image be downloaded, if not there already?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  The REST API, for creating containers, is very step-by-step, and the 'docker run' command does multiple operations.

Using strace, you can see some of the POST requests it makes to the API even for a simple `docker run hello-world` including:

```
POST /v1.40/containers/create
POST /v1.40/images/create
POST /v1.40/containers/create
POST /v1.40/containers/[hash]/attach
POST /v1.40/containers/[hash]/wait
POST /v1.40/containers/[hash]/start
```

When the first create request fails, it moves forward and pulls the image, then re-issues the create.  It also needs to take care of attaching to and starting the container.  You would need to mimic the appropriate operations for your own use of the API.

The [API Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#) even calls this out:

> Most of the client's commands map directly to API endpoints (e.g. `docker ps` is GET `/containers/json`). The notable exception is running containers, which consists of several API calls.

Answer (score 0):

ok so this is the expected behavior as per: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30658